# Binding Grid field to XML String element

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using Telerik's RadGrid in this case, but I don't think that really matters as far as this question is concerned. I have XML Strings in a format like this:

```
<Root>
    <Sub>
        <Name>a</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <Name>b</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Sub>
</Root>
```

Upon databinding I create columns for all of the different `Name` values and now I want to databind to the `Value` on each row?

When exporting this data using sql (in the same format) I can use

```
Root.value('(Root/Sub[Name="a")/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'a'
```

so I basically need something that does that, but when binding to a row on a grid based on an xml string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following online demos:

- [Grid - Programmatic Creation from XML](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/gridfromxml/defaultcs.aspx)
- [Grid - Editing XML Using XmlDataSource](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/xmldatasource/defaultcs.aspx)